# How do I press Control + Alt + KP4 on an Apple Wireless Keyboard - French?

Tags: keyboard

I have an [Apple Wireless Keyboard - French](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC184F/B).

Could anyone tell me which shortcut is for the number lock? <kbd>clear</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd> as suggested somewhere does not seem to work.

Also, where are number keys when the number keyboard is on?

Finally, how to press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>KP4</kbd>

Comment: Are you sure it *has* a number keypad? I know the US version hasn't had one for quite a while, and that doesn't look like it does either.